# Not able to do multitouch gestures(except two finger scrolling) on touchpad

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

On the site: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch

It says that unity supports 3 finger pinch to maximize/restore windows and many more gestures.

I am not able to use these multi touch features.
I can only use two finger scrolling and nothing else.
My synclient prpperties are also right.

I am using

- ubuntu 12.04
- intel i5 sony vaio laptop
- My system is up to date.

Comment: I am having the same problem on my Toshiba NB505. I also have 12.04 and everything is up to date.

Comment: Does in your laptop two finger scrolling works?

Comment: Yup. It's the exact same situation you described.

Comment: Still reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

On my Sony Vaio VPCEG15FB on Ubuntu 14.04 when I use two fingers spaced on touchpad (to up or down) I have the following results:

**On firefox:**
Scrolling

**On Shotwell**
Zoom

**File (Explorer)**
Scrolling

On https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/TouchpadSupport say:
*"Unfortunately, X can't send touch events if it is also sending other events caused by the same touches. For example, if you have two finger scrolling enabled for a touchpad, X can't send touch events until you put three touches down."*